# obtaining details about caller object for a procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure A which is calling another procedure B. I want to know if it is possible, in B, to get information about object that invoked it. My real purpose is to suppress the output of B if it is being called from A, else display it's output if it is invoked from outside A.

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: yes, it is very possible. Give it a shot :p

Comment: @Drew any pointers on how can we do that?

Comment: Have A pass a parameter. Maybe, 'fromA'. The others do 'notFromA'

Comment: If you are asking if there is some kind of call stack, I doubt it. Like, referrer. Just pass a parameter like `squelch` yay or nay or something.

Comment: yep...i had that thought too...was just trying to see if an extra parameter can be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pratik, I think the below will be very obvious. A test section is at the bottom. `procB` will not render the resultset if called by `procA` accordingly (by the parameter). If called outside of `procA`, according to the parameter, it will render the resultset. So you can build your building block(s) that way.

**Schema:**

```
drop table if exists flimFlam;
create table flimFlam
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null,
    calledBy varchar(100) not null,
    theWhen datetime not null
);
```

**Two procs:**

```
drop procedure if exists procA;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure procA()
BEGIN
    call procB('fromA');
    select 7 as seven;
END$$
DELIMITER $$

drop procedure if exists procB;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure procB(fromWhom varchar(20))
BEGIN
    insert flimFlam(thing,calledBy,theWhen) select 'blah',fromWhom,now();
    IF fromWhom != 'fromA' THEN
        select * from flimFlam;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER $$
```

Test:

```
-- truncate table flimFlam;
call procB('Not from procA');
call procB('Not from procA');
call procA();
select * from flimFlam;
+----+-------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | thing | calledBy       | theWhen             |
+----+-------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 | blah  | Not from procA | 2016-07-18 00:07:21 |
|  2 | blah  | Not from procA | 2016-07-18 00:07:29 |
|  3 | blah  | fromA          | 2016-07-18 00:07:43 |
+----+-------+----------------+---------------------+
```